# Python: When trying to compile to exe missing module 'queue'?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, pyinstaller, importerror, cx-freeze

With both `pyinstaller` and `cxfreeze` I get this **error**:

```
C:\Users\asdasda\Desktop\dist>test.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
 line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module
>
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
 line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 28, in
<module>
  File "site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 203, in l
oad_module
  File "site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 115, in _
resolve
  File "site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _i
mport_module
ImportError: No module named 'queue'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
 line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
 line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
 line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
 line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\requests\compat.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
 line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
 line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
 line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 203, in load_module
  File "site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
  File "site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
ImportError: No module named 'queue'
Failed to execute script test
```

I tried compiling the exact same script that I compiled a few months ago (*It worked that time*) but now I get the error which made me think that it was a `python` version error, so I switched from *3.4.4* to *3.5.2* but that didn't help.

I also tried different versions of `pyinstaller` and `cxfreeze` but all gave me the same error.

Please help me regarding this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried the development tip of pyinstaller?

Comment: @StephenRauch I did but still the same outcome, very confused right now since the module 'queue' doesn't even exist

Comment: queue is python stdlib, so it really ought to be there: https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html.  GL.

Comment: Yeah, and it is in my python folder which is why I'm so confused

Answer (score 1):

cxfreeze seems to not support the most recent version `requests`. This error was fixed for me by downgrading to v2.11.1

`pip install requests==2.11.1`

Comment: Thank you, I confirm that 2.11.1 works fine also.  I [opened a Requests issue](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/4561).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes imports are not detected. I had the same problem with the queue module.
Adding the `queue` module to the hidden imports in the `.spec` file solved the problem for me (PyInstaller):

```
a = Analysis(..., 
             hiddenimports=['queue'],
             ...)
```

- [source](https://github.com/fossasia/kniteditor/blob/master/windows-build/KnitEditor.spec#L15)